# selection.addRange not working correctly in safari but is in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, safari, selection, cursor-position

So we're using Guardian's scribe WYSIWYG editor and attempting to set the cursor inside one the markers. In chrome everything works smoothly. But in Safari the selection is popping out of the editor and moving down to the next sibling's #textNode. Here's the html structure:

[image]

Essentially what scribe to add the range is the normal implementation. I've even tried writing it my self as follows.;

```
sel = document.getSelection();
range = document.getRange();
markers = document.querySelectorAll('.scribe-editor-marker');
range.setStartBefore(markers[0])
range.setEndAfter(markers.length >= 2 ? markers[1] : markers[0]);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

In Chrome and Firefox the cursor goes back to the scribe-editor-marker but in safari it doesn't. I even tried just placing the selection the p tag wrapping the marker from the console and it did the same thing.

Below is a picture of the range before and after addRange is performed.

[image]

Any thoughts?

EDIT: for reference here's the UI.

[image]